# What is local variable and objects in memory model?

Tags: java

I have a class given below. In this class what are the variable going to store in heap and what are the variable going to store in Thread stack of java memory model. I know that local variable is stored in stack and objects stored in heap. but I need explanation from given class.

```
class School {

     public int id =1;

     public Student student=new Student();;

     public void method(Student st, int f ){

        Student stud = new Student();
        int fees = 100;
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: You stated two facts that can easily be applied to the given code. Is your homework *that* difficult for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the two things needed to answer the questions are stated in the question.

Comment: hi, I am actually confused with what is local variable and objects. I am thinking that objects inside a method also a local variable. but in memory model these objects are stored in heap. How its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Student stud` is a *reference* to an object, not an object.  The reference is on the stack, the object is on the heap.

```
Student stud = new Student();
        ^            ^
reference on stack   object on heap
```

NOTE: With Escape Analysis, an object can be placed on the stack as well, though this is an optimisation you generally don't need to know is happening.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lawrey its very helpful for me. I have one another doubt please tell me

 if stud.id = 5;

then where it will store?

Comment: @Robin `stud` is a reference on the stack, `id` is a field in the object which is on the heap.

Comment: hi Peter Lawrey, thanks for helping, I have another doubt that if have created 4 new object with different reference inside a method. is this will create 4 new object in heap or 1 object?

Comment: @Robin if you use `new` 4 times, you will create 4 objects.